# How to pass an array of primitive element type from javascript to wasm in Rust fast?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

Let me ask how to pass an array holding uint8 elements from javascript to wasm in Rust fast?

I found one method in: [As JsValue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/964).

Though I wonder if there is some clearly faster one when all element values are same primitive type and in a particular range.

For example, you encode a uint8 array to a string then pass the string to wasm not through JsValue.

Or I wonder if you can pass any array of primitive element type to wasm not through JsValues.

Edit: After reading the first answer, I tried to follow the answer with my understanding as follows. It seems to be successful. Is my understanding correct?

```
import * as wasm from "../pkg";
import * as bg_wasm from '../pkg/PACKAGE_NAME_bg.wasm';
const RUST_STRUCT = wasm.RUST_STRUCT.new();

const cellsPtr = RUST_STRUCT.cells();
const cells = new Uint8Array(bg_wasm.memory.buffer, cellsPtr, 100);
console.log( cells[50]);// 0
for(let i=0;i<100;i++){cells[i]=i;}
console.log( cells[50]);//50
console.log( "end");
```

[Vec::leak](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.leak)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WASM virtual machine has its own memory address space, that is seen from JS as a big `ArrayBuffer` usually named `wasm.memory`. Any value that you pass from JS to WASM has to be copied from its own variable to that memory.

But there is a nice trick. If you allocate a buffer from Rust side, such a `Vec<u8>`, and then somehow pass a reference to it to JS, then the `&mut [u8]` will become a JS `Uint8Array`, that is actually a direct view of the Rust memory. Zero copy overhead.

You just have to be careful not to use the reference from JS in a way that breaks any Rust invariant, such as passing it back as another reference, such that you get two `&mut _` to the same value. Also you have to keep this memory alive in Rust for as long as JS holds the reference. It may even be a good idea to call `Vec::leak()` into your buffer so that its memory lives forever.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. As a very beginner in this topic, I somehow read your text to encourage that my javascript can set new values  on elements of the [u8] array if I am enough careful. Does it?

Comment: @skatori: Yes, correct. You have to be careful that you obey the Rust aliasing rules, though, that can be a bit tricky: basically you should only write to that buffer when Rust considers that it is mutably borrowed by the external code, such as calling a JS function from Rust and passing the `&mut [u8]`. Or alternatively, do `Vec::leak` in Rust, pass the reference to JS and forget that from Rust; then you can write from JS freely and pass to Rust slices of that memory.